# How do I use a reference to a property in an interface as a type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

In this app I'm writing, there's an interface that controls the settings; here's an example of what it may look like:

```
export interface Config {
  volume: number
  graphics: string
  darkMode: boolean
}
```

Which I then have a class that implements it that looks like this:

```
import {Config} from './config'

export class DefaultConfig implements Config {
  volume = 100
  graphics = 'low' // I'd usually use an enum for this, but this is just an example
  darkMode = false
}
```

Which finally get loaded into a Settings class that looks like this:

```
import {DefaultConfig} from './default-config'

export abstract class Settings {
  static config = new DefaultConfig()
}
```

So, the issue is that I want the user to be able to change, for example, the volume using an HTML range input element. The question I want to know the answer to is: how can I specify a type where it has to be a property of a class that has a type of number? For example:

```
import {Settings} from './settings'
import {HtmlUiElement} from './html-ui-element'

export class HtmlSettingSlider extends HtmlUiElement {
  protected setting: number // What type can I put here instead?
  // Code to assign, change, read from the setting goes here
}
```

I want to assign to the `setting` property, for example: `Settings.config.volume`

While 'number' technically works, it's not type protected; I want it to be a requirement that it's a value of Config with the type number. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to do this

```js
export class HtmlSettingSlider implements HtmlUiElement {
    protected setting: Config[keyof Config] & number
}
```

Now I'm completely lost with all of your classes. I think you overcomplicate things and I would advise you to use plain old Javascript objects when possible like so.

```js
const defaultConfig: Config = {
    volume: 100,
    graphics: 'low', 
    darkMode:false
};
```

But I'm probably missing something

Comment: The problem is that this forces the class to use only volume, but if I wanted to add another slider and setting with numerical value, this would no longer work.

Comment: In this case you could use `protected setting: Config[keyof Config]`

Comment: Is there anyway I can make it to be only if that key leads to a property with the type of number?

Comment: Yep `Config[keyof Config] & number` maybe I should edit my answer accordingly

Comment: Ooh, this is a really good demonstration of what I can do with intersections. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That will only work if you define a different interface for each variable inside Settings. Something like this.

```
export interface Volume {
    value: boolean;
}

export interface Graphics {
    value: string;
}
```

export interface DarkMode {
value: boolean;
}

```
export interface Config {
    volume: Volume;
    graphics: Graphics;
    darkMode: DarkMode;
```

}

Now you're safe and can control which Type of value to go in. Then you can say:

```
setting: Volume = Settings.config.volume;
```